# React Native crash ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, react-native

I made an app using React Native and uploaded it to play store, but there is a crash happened about 800 times in the last month reported in Google play console and I cannot find why it's happening.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2274)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2417)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1342)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5322)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:829)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:645)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2265)
```

How to find the problem to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably ProGuard stripping some classes. Usually the Support Classes. Try this:

-keep class android.support.** { *; }

-keep interface android.support.** { *; }

Comment: I will try this in the next release and reply if it succeeded, Thanks.